# Six words in a 3x3 grid

Tags: crosswords, word-square

Can you place 9 letters in a 3x3 grid such that each row and column forms a **distinct** 3-letter word? Rows are read left to right, while columns are read top to bottom. I will accept words that are found in this Scrabble [dictionary](https://scrabblewordfinder.org/dictionary-checker).

Comment: We... Have a lot of [tag:word-square] puzzles, and I'm really sure you can find a lot of possible answers... Sorry, I'm downvoting this as I personally consider this as low-effort.

Comment: Sorry if this is a repeat. Feel free to close. I don't normally make word puzzles.

Comment: This is *not* exactly a repeat, but there are puzzles which are using 3x3 grid (or maybe larger) and acts like a crossword (with some given clues for example.) So simply asking the existence of it seems off. Anyway, if you are interested, here is a great 3x3 word puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/75268/28719 :)

Comment: I guess there is no point asking about the 4x4 version of this puzzle?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Word square](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square). See variant forms/double word squares.

Comment: Well there you go...I had no idea that this was such a common puzzle. Daniel thank you for the Wikipedia link - very interesting.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky What can make these sqares specific and difficult is the inclusion of Diagonal words. Also to make it unique you can add the middle letter??

Comment: guys come on stop minusing me!!! I've learned my lesson already!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question to prevent it from turning into an open-ended list of all possible 3x3 word squares

Comment: I voted to close it :) Never liked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z Z Z
Z Z Z
Z Z Z

You didn't say "distinct" and zzz is on the list.

Update:

T O O
U R N
B E E

Comment: Ah sorry, yes should be distinct. Will fix!

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: Amazingly the secondary diagonal also makes a word (orb or bro). Can we make the primary diagonal also a word?

Comment: It would have been appropriate to include the fact that your update was taken directly from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square)

Answer (score 3):

> R  E  F
>  O  A  R
>  D  R  Y

works in 8 directions (left to right, top to bottom and both diagonals). One of many solutions I imagine :)